# VBA - Find row number or return row number of next empty cell

Tags: excel, vba, rowcount

I'm struggling to get the code below to work and would really appreciate any support.

I can find the row number that contains a variable ID number - findRow which works fine.

I want to return the row number of the next available empty row if findRow = 0. I am using findNextRow to try and accomplish this, but clearly I am missing something.

```
Function findId(ids As String) As Integer
    Dim findRow As Range
    Dim findNextRow As Range
    
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    
    Set findRow = Selection.Find(What:=ids, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
    Set findNextRow = Selection.Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        
    
    If Not findRow Is Nothing Then
        findId = findRow.Row
        
    ElseIf Not findRow Is Nothing Then
        findId = findNextRow.Row
        
    Else
        findId = 0
        
            End If
    
End Function
```

EDIT
The function is being called on here:

```
Sub Import()
    Dim Drop As Worksheet
    Dim Data As Worksheet

    Set Drop = Worksheets("Drop")
    Set Data = Worksheets("Data")

    Dim idRow As Integer
    idRow = findId(Drop.Range("A2"))

    If (idRow = 0) Then
        MsgBox ("ID not found")
        End
    End If

    Drop.Range("A2:DS2").Copy
    Data.Range("A" & idRow & ":DS" & idRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Call CopyPaste(Drop.Range("A" & idRow & ":R" & idRow), _
        Data.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))

End Sub
```

I've tried using the updated function as suggested:

```
Function findId(ids As String) As Long
    Dim m
    With Sheets("Data")
        m = Application.Match(ids, .Columns("A"), 0) 'any match on id?
        'got a match?  If not get next empty cell
        If IsError(m) Then m = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    findId = CLng(m)
End Function
```

But can't get this to find a match. Should it matter that `Match(ids,` is located on a different sheet to `.Columns("A")`?

Comment: I'm thinking you are trying to select ranges in a function, you need to set the ranges, not select them for example : `set rng=sheets("Data").range("A:A")`, then use that rng as the search range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Function findId(id As String) As Long
    Dim m
    With Sheets("Data")
        m = Application.Match(id, .Columns("A"), 0) 'any match on id?
        'got a match?  If not get next empty cell
        If IsError(m) Then m = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    findId = CLng(m)
End Function
```

FYI there's no reason in VBA to use `Integer` over `Long`, and using longs is safer when dealing with ranges, since integer will overflow above approx. 32,000

Comment: Thanks Tim, solved one problem but can't get the Match function to work now. Edit above to show how the function is being used

Comment: It doesn't matter if the lookup range is on a different sheet from the value you're looking for.  Maybe you can post some examples of what your id's look like?  Might be a formatting issue.

Comment: Thank you again! The id's were numbers, I amended `ids as string` to `ids as long` and now all working perfectly.